# Python 3.8 (pandas): how to call column header containing percent (%) symbol

Tags: python, pandas, keyerror

I want to read .csv files containing two columns, one called 'nm' and one called '%R'. Say I read the file as

```
file = pd.read_csv(path, header=0, delimiter=',')
```

The file looks something like this.

[image: Example of what the file looks like]

Now when I want to call the first column (`file['nm']`) there are no problems. But when I try to read `file['%R']`, I get a KeyError:

```
file['%R'] Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\XXXXX\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2895, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 70, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 101, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1675, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1683, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

KeyError: '%R'


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-51-66fff2b16d36>", line 1, in <module>
    file['%R']

  File "C:\Users\XXXXX\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2902, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)

  File "C:\Users\XXXXX\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2897, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err

KeyError: '%R'
```

I've tried to call it as `file['%%R']`, `file['\%R']` and also a non-existing column name such as `file['abc']` as well but I get the same type of error. To me it seems like the column name I'm trying to call is not recognized. How can I call the '%R' column without getting this error?

I'm using Python 3.8.

Comment: what is `print (fil.columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I just received feedback that this question has been answered elsewhere, unfortunately I could not find it before. ```print (file.columns.tolist())``` returns ```['nm', ' %R']```, so there was a whitespace before the %. It was fixed by adding ```skipinitialspace=True``` to the ```pd.read_csv``` line.